# Hash a password and save it and the salt to mysql pdo utf8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I have this question, excuse me if it is not appropriate, tell me in the comments and I will drop it. The thing is as follows: 
I generate a salt with this code:

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
```

And the password this way:

```
$password =  hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);
```

and save $salt and $password to the MYSQL database, there is no problem so far, if I connect this way:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName',
    'username',
    'password'
);
```

But if I connect this other way:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName;charset=utf8',
    'username',
    'password'
);
```

the salt does not save into the database or save with a wrong value and length; unless I do this:
 $salt = utf8_encode( mcrypt_create_iv(32););
But I think it is not right, I mean why I should encode that, what is the problem with mcrypt_create_iv(32) and utf-8 ?

Comment: your IV is going to be essentially "random" binary garbage. If you're putting it into a text/varchar field, it'll be subject to the field's charset translation rules. binary data should go into varbinary/blob fields instead. neither of those has charsets, and what you put into the field will be what comes out of it.

Comment: So changing the tipe of the field to blob will made it agnostic about the charset of the connection, is what you are saying

Comment: that's the point of binary/blob fields. no charsets to randomly trash the data due to incorrect application of translation rules that should never get applied to the data in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

**Your solution will work:**

`mcrypt_create_iv` returns a bunch of bytes, which are conveniently put in a string. But because they can have any value, they might result in an incorrect UTF-8 sequence. `utf8_encode` fixes that, and will work fine as long as you also remember to use `utf8_decode` after you read it back from the database.

If your connection isn't utf8, then each byte will be treated as a single (whole) ANSI character, and you won't need anything to encode that.

**Best solution: keep it binary:**

Since this data is actually binary data that is not really a string, a binary field (BINARY, VARBINARY or BLOB) would be a better choice for storing it to prevent any problems due to encoding or decoding.

`BINARY` is probably the best choice, since this data is neither variable in length, nor large.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

**Alternative: store as actual text, without fancy characters:**

Another solution is using [`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) to convert the binary data to a hexadecimal representation. The string will be twice as long, but it contains only letters and numbers, and is safe to story in about any type of string field. You can convert it back using `hex2bin`.

Comment: Ok thanks I now understand, also I'd like to ask you if there is no security concerns about encoding it with utf-8?

Comment: There might be. I would choose to save this information in its original binary format in a `BINARY` field.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have mentioned mcrypt_create_iv can generate characters the do not fit in utf8. Try something like this:

```
function generate_random($length=16, $simple=false){
        $result='';
        $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()+=-_?~';
        if($simple)
            $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
            $result .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
        return $result;
    }
```

16 characters with a character set of 78 yields 1.877 * 10^30 combinations. That plus the password length should be more than sufficient for a one-way hash like sha256.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It seems like DIY work, how is called your way of coding without brackets?